# Angular2 - Nginx route 404 error on cloudfoundry

Tags: angular, nginx, cloud-foundry, nginx-location

I am using cloud foundry platform to deploy angular2 app using nginx based ststicfile buildpack.

Upon refreshing on a sub route `/my-route` I am getting 404.
I want any path such as `www.mysite.com/some-ng2-router-path` to redirect back to `www.mysite.com`

I have seen several posts about this but I can't figure out how to edit the nginx.conf file on the server, and I do not want to use the hash bang approach.

What do I do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to enable push state routing?  i.e. add this line to the Staticfile, `pushstate: enabled`.   http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html

Comment: Edited the question to clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to map routes within your app? e.g. cf map-route angular-app mysite.com --hostname www --path some-ng2-router-path

More on https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#map-route

It should work with http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#pushstate

Comment: Well I didn't think it would work at first because I am not using the hashbang approach. But even without the route mapping, adding pushstate: enabled to Staticfile in root dir worked like a charm thanks alot!

Comment: So what did you do Sir, Can you explain a bit more ?

Answer (score 2):

No route mapping is needed. Create a file named `Staticfile` that is in your root. The contents of the `Staticfile` should be:

```
pushstate: enabled
```

The buildpack docs include other options you can enable for nginx: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#pushstate