# angular 4 application routing issues when deployed in cloud foundry

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, cloud-foundry

I have a unique routing issue here, I have an angular application which works fine at my local, but when the application is deployed to the cloud foundry the routing simply does not work at all(it gives 404).

Here is the code snippet of routing

```
import  { LocationStrategy,  PathLocationStrategy }  from  '@angular/common';
const  appRoutes:  Routes  =   [{
  path:   '',
  component:  PageNotFoundComponent
 },
 {
  path:   'contents',
  component:  ContentsComponent
 },
 {
  path:   'sidebar',
  component:  SidebarComponent
 }
];
```

I am looking for these:

routing conditions:

1. Routing without hashing.
2. Entering URL directly to the browser should navigate to the page.
3. 404 error should not be shown.

Any suggestion?

Comment: You probably just need to enable pushstate routing in the staticfile buildpack. See here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42465155/angular2-nginx-route-404-error-on-cloudfoundry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use **.HTACCESS** file with routing conditions.
Use the "php_buildpack" as the buildpack while deploying the application to the cloud foundry

The routing condition used in the .htaccess file

`RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

## not rewrite css, js and images

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import  { LocationStrategy,  PathLocationStrategy }  from  '@angular/common';
const  appRoutes:  Routes  =   [{
  path:   '',
  redirectTo:'contents',
  pathMatch:'full'
 },
 {
  path:   'contents',
  component:  ContentsComponent
 },
 {
  path:   'sidebar',
  component:  SidebarComponent
 },
 {
  path:'**',
  component:PageNotFoundComponent
];
```

for deplyment issues goto https://angular.io/guide/deployment

you will get a solution according to your server

or deply with node server